# Is Mono a subset of .NET?

Tags: .net, mono

I know the converse is not true, but if my application works using Mono is it guaranteed to work if I switch to the real deal? If not, where can I find a list of caveats?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Both Mono and .NET are supersets of the ECMA/ISO CLI family of specifications. However, neither .NET nor Mono are subsets of the other. Both Mono and .NET add features on top of ECMA/ISO CLI, but while Mono implements many of .NET's additions, .NET does not implement any of Mono's additions.

Here's a few examples:

- Mono has larger arrays. This is actually *not* an added feature to the ECMA/ISO CLI specification but an optional one: the specification says that array indices must be either 32 bit or 64 bit. .NET chose 32 bit but Mono chose 64, since arrays with 10 billion entries and more are quite common in supercomputing applications, where Mono has quite a strong market share. So, if your app has an array with several billions of entries, it will run just fine on Mono but won't work on .NET.
- Mono has continuations built into the VM. These are important for game programming.
- Mono has native SIMD support for parallel operations on arrays, which are mapped to native CPU SIMD instructions (MMX, SSE, VMX).
- Mono has compiler-as-a-service, which Microsoft has been only vaguely talking about for some unspecified future version of .NET.
- Mono has a lot of additional libraries, especially bindings to graphics libraries other than Windows Forms (wx.NET, Gtk#, Cocoa#, ...)

Note, however, that (except for the arrays), all of these are clearly distinguishible by their namespaces, since none of them live in the `System` or `Microsoft` namespaces.

---

EDIT: Actually, most of the above-mentioned extensions are explicitly designed to also work on .NET. For example, `Mono.Simd` also runs on .NET, but without the runtime support that the Mono VM has, it's unusably slow. (Basically, all the SIMD operations are implemented in C#, but the Mono compiler detects those calls and replaces them with their corresponding assembly instructions. That way, they work on .NET, but without the special treatment, they are significantly slower.) Also, the C# REPL is currently being re-implemented on top of `Reflection.Emit` (at the moment, it calls the Mono compiler directly), so that it will work on .NET in the future. Gtk# works just fine on Windows and .NET.

Only the `Mono.Tasklet` library cannot be implemented on .NET, since it requires VM-level support for continuations.

Comment: Mono.SIMD does work on the .NET runtime however, since it reverts to software.

Comment: @Matt Olenik: Thanks. Apparently, I confused SIMD and continuations. SIMD works, but is slow, `Mono.Tasklet` doesnt'.

Answer (score 3):

No. Mono includes several alternative UI frameworks (Gtk#, wxWindows for .NET, etc).

If you only use Microsoft-defined classes, though, you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

Mono is an implementation of the [CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Infrastructure) standard, as is the [CLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime).

It includes many of the libraries you would find in the .NET BCL, but not any that are windows specific (WMI is one whole domain that comes to mind).

So long as you keep to features that are not windows specific, you should be fine.

The mono team have created a tool to check if your code should work on mono - [MoMA](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA), the Mono Migration Analyzer.

As far as using mono code with the Microsoft compilers, so long as you include the libraries you are using and are not doing any pInvokes on linux, you should be fine.

Comment: I am talking about the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

Mono does not extend BCL APIs, at least not in the `System` namespace. Therefore, you can be quite certain that an application using only types from the `System` namespace will be portable without recompilation from Mono to .NET. Of course, you won't find anything in the `Mono` namespace once you're in .NET world.

From the [Mono FAQ](http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_Technical):

> **Do you plan to Embrace and Extend .NET?**
>
> Embracing a good technology is good.
>   Extending technologies in incompatible
>   ways is bad for the users, so we do
>   not plan on making incompatible
>   changes to the technologies.
>
> If you have innovative ideas, and want
>   to create new classes, we encourage
>   you to make those classes operate
>   correctly well in both Mono and .NET.
>   Today Mono ships with a number of
>   extra libraries that were developed
>   either by members of the Mono
>   community, or other groups. **In some
>   cases, we have found the bits from
>   Microsoft to be incomplete, but we
>   avoid breaking the API, instead we
>   expose the missing functionality in
>   new assemblies** (see Mono.Security)

Comment: +1, that's an important point which I forgot to mention in my answer: almost all of those "proprietary" extensions the Mono team has done, were in library form, so that they also work on .NET. The continuations, for example, have VM support in Mono, but they also work on .NET. They are much too slow to be actually usable, but they *do* work (for a rather generous definition of "work", at least.) The C# REPL, which used the Mono compiler directly, is currently in the process of being re-implemented on top of `Reflection.Emit`. The only thing which cannot be supported on .NET, is `Mono.Simd`.

Comment: I confused SIMD and continuations. Actually, it is the other way around: SIMD works on .NET, by emulating the CPU-level SIMD instructions in C#. Continuations don't, since they require VM-level continuation support.